# Django MPTT : Filter by depth?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt, mptt

I would like to know a thing about django-mptt, as I'm considering using it for a engineering coordination project.

I would have a Model class (say, 'Interface'), with a ForeignKey to the Model (say, 'Location') in the Tree.

Will I be able to filter Interfaces by the depth of the Location they refer to ? The depth being the number of parents.

I don't know yet how to organize my data, this is why I'm asking. I'm considering using django-mptt (opposed to Models created by a loop at deployment time, each Model corresponding to a tree level), but I am scared that it would block me at a point and force me to review my whole project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found my answer finally : [django-mptt dev documentation](http://django-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/technical_details.html#level)

> Level The level (or “depth”) at which a node sits in the tree.
>
> Root nodes are level 0, their immediate children are level 1, their
>   immediate children are level 2 and so on...
>
> This field is purely denormalisation for convenience. It avoids the
>   need to examine the tree structure to determine the level of a
>   particular node and makes queries which need to take depth into
>   account easier to implement using Django’s ORM. For example, limiting
>   the number of levels of nodes which are retrieved for the whole tree
>   or any subtree:

```
# Retrieve root nodes and their immediate children only
SomeModel.tree.filter(level__lte=1)
```